# what is causing this segmentation fault? example from book

Tags: c

I am going through a book and I tried running this example but I receive a segmentation fault - gdb says it's when it sets argv[0] = filename;

this code is copied/pasted straight from book's downloadable code samples.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char filename[] = "/bin/sh\x00";
  char **argv, **envp; // arrays that contain char pointers

  argv[0] = filename; // only argument is filename - segmentation fault here
  argv[1] = 0;  // null terminate the argument array

  envp[0] = 0; // null terminate the environment array

  execve(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

Edit: The book is Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson, which has VERY good reviews.  This specific example is used as the first tutorial on converting C into machine code in the shellcode section, specifically it is exec_shell.c and can be downloaded from http://nostarch.com/hacking2/htm .  I imagine some context around the use of this code was necessary in order to avoid some of the negative comments below, sorry for leaving details out, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the name and author of the book so that others may avoid it.

Comment: shouldn't there be a strcpy rather than a direct string assignment?

Comment: @crypto: `char filename[] = "/bin/sh\x00";` **is** a copy

Comment: @crypto no `strcpy` is needed because `execve` doesn’t modify the string. Therefore you might as well just pass it a pointer to the static string.

Comment: @Daniel & @pmg, points taken.

Comment: Actually @pmg is more right than me, `filename` isn’t a pointer to a static string, it’s a copy on the stack. Since there’s no need for that I’d probably change `char filename[]` to `char *filename`, but that’s not really relevant to the question :).

Comment: so, does the fact that this is meant to be used as shellcode change anything?

Comment: doran: I’m guessing that in the book this code gets disassembled and incorporated into an assembly language program, in which case argv and envp are just placeholders.

Answer (score 11):

It obviously isn’t a very good book. The problem is that neither `argv` nor `envp` are initialized, so when you write to `argv[0]`, you’re trying to overwrite some random location in memory.

Try something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char *filename = "/bin/sh";
  char *argv[2], *envp[1];

  argv[0] = filename;
  argv[1] = 0;

  envp[0] = 0;

  execve(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

This alternative initializes `argv` and `envp` on the stack, with enough space to contain two pointers and one pointer respectively.

In the code above, I’ve made one additional change to repair an additional common (but, in this case, harmless) misunderstanding. The `\x00` that was at the end of `"/bin/sh\x00"` is redundant, since in C static strings are implicitly null-terminated. `"/bin/sh\x00"` is a string terminated by *two* nulls.

Alternatively, as pointed out by [caf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf), here is a more compact example with exactly equivalent meaning:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char *filename = "/bin/sh";
  char *argv[2] = { filename, 0 };
  char *envp[1] = { 0 };

  execve(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

Comment: the argv & envp pointers are fine, but who's going to allocate space to store their contents (not the pointers)?

Comment: The string `"/bin/sh/\x00"` is allocated statically. `argv` doesn’t have any other contents. `envp` doesn’t have any contents at all.

Comment: In fact you might as well just have `char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", 0 }, *envp[] = { 0 };`

Answer (score 3):

You never allocate the "arrays of pointers" meant to go in `argv` and `envp`!  What book is it, that omits such crucial steps?!

Either add `argv = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*))` (and similarly for `envp`) before you start assigning to `argv[0]` and friends, or change `argv`'s and `envp`'s declarations to be arrays of pointers rather than pointers to pointers (the latter's quite a feasible approach, in this specific case, since you do know exactly how many pointers you need in each at the time you're writing the code -- dynamic allocation is therefore somewhat supererogatory;-).

Comment: Should be allocating 2*sizeof(char*)

Comment: @Andrew, entirely correct, tx and +1 for spotting my typo (I've edited the A to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

`char **argv`

`argv` is pointing to a memory location which you are not allowed to access/write to. It is something that is better known as a [wild pointer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to get a better book!  In this code `argv` is a pointer with no storage allocated to it and pointing at random memory (or probably `NULL`).  When you dereference it with `argv[0] = ...`, your code ends up trying to write to random memory.  Your variable declaration should be something more like:

```
char *argv[3], *envp[1];
```

Comment: It's probably not `NULL`. I don't know of any operating system or runtime that normally zeros out memory on launch, and no implicit initialization is done for automatic variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where did you get this book, but it obviously sucks. `argv` is an **uninitialized** pointer, it holds a random address. Hence accessing it will most probably lead to the access violation.

Answer (score 0):

Before using such multi-level pointers, I recommend reading up on dynamic memmory allocation in C.

Whenever you use pointers, you must also think whether you need to allocate space for the data that the pointers are going to point to (as also the pointers themselves, for multi-level pointers).

For example,

```
char **bar;
```

here, bar allocates space for 1 pointer-to-pointer, ie. enough space to store one address. This is not very useful without any additional data allocation.

In reality, you should be doing:

```
char **bar = calloc( 2 , sizeof(char *) );
```

here, bar allocates space for 1 pointer-to-pointer, ie. again, space to store one address as bar, AND 2 consecutive locations for storing 2 more pointers, namely bar[0] & bar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3LmN.png).

```
char bar[0]= calloc( 10 , sizeof(char) );
```

here, bar[0] allocates space for storing a string of size 10 - 1 (for \0 at end).

Now, if you do a string copy:

```
strcpy(bar[0],"Hello!");
```

the final memory map comes to: (addresses in circles, contents in blocks)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Many of the people here are on the right track, but missing some of the numerous problems here.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char filename[] = "/bin/sh\x00";
  char **argv, **envp; // arrays that contain char pointers

  argv[0] = filename; // only argument is filename - segmentation fault here
  argv[1] = 0;  // null terminate the argument array

  envp[0] = 0; // null terminate the environment array

  execve(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

The problems here are:
**1.**  The pointer array of character strings is never initialized.  Pointers take up space too, and thus an array of pointers needs to use malloc in c.
**2.**  Each character pointer in your pointer array needs its own malloc statement before use.

Here is the working code, with printouts to show you what is going on:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  unsigned int i=0;
  char filename[] = "/bin/sh\x00";
  char **argv; // arrays that contain char pointers

  argv=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
  argv[0]=(char *)malloc(strlen(filename)*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(argv[0],filename);

  printf("Arg 0 is %u chars long...\n",strlen(argv[0]));
  printf("Arg 0 is ");
  while (argv[0][i] != '\0') {
    printf("%c",argv[0][i]);
    i++;
  }
  printf("!\n");

  free(argv[0]);
}
```

Comment: Err. No. In this case you **can** directly assign one character array to another. It’s an area to be careful around, certainly, and if in doubt it’s best to make a copy. But, in this case we know that `execve` won’t modify the strings (its arguments are defined like `char *const argv[]`). We also know that the strings won’t get used after the function returns (because `execve` never returns). So, there’s no reason to waste time and effort copying the strings. Just give `execve` pointers to the original strings and be done.

Comment: Also, if your code did call `execve`, it wouldn’t work, because `execve` requires that the `argv` and `envp` arrays are terminated by a null pointer, and you only made room for one pointer in `argv`.

Comment: Point taken.  They're just assigning the char pointer to the previously allocated character array, so that is acceptable.  Still better to perform a malloc/strcpy to create a fresh copy, just to be safe and prevent accidental modification in longer programs.  Just be sure to clean up your new memory with free at the end of your program (as I did).